AUTO REPEAT DATA using formula EXCEL
I have a master data with a number. i would like to repeat the data based on the number inserted, and then automatically detect where to repeat the formula. Example as picture below.
for repetitive, i have found a formula,
(Formula in G4)
=TRANSPOSE(TEXTSPLIT(REPT(B4&",",$E$4),","))

But how do i make it auto detect that the name "sarah" has ended the repetition, and auto start with formula for "Kimi"?


We do not accept posts demanding URGENT HELP. Your question is no more urgent than that of anyone else here. Volunteers answer questions for free, and do so on their own time. If you can't wait until one of them finds your post and answers it like everyone else, then feel free to hire someone to do it for you and pay them enough to make it a high priority. For more information, see Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?

@KenWhite Sir, I have removed that statement of OP because it doesn't looks good from OP's end

@MayukhBhattacharya: Yes, I know you removed it. I was removing it also, but you beat me to it by about one second. The OP needs to be made aware that it is inappropriate here, so they don't repeat the conduct in the future.

@KenWhite Sir absolutely agreed!.

thank you guys for the comment.. understand that next time i shouldn't use the word. but if i would like to clarify, its just simply my expression and because I was in an event that i needed the solution in a few minutes before my presentation.. but again, i understand on the reason not to use "urgent" as others might need the same urgency as i do. Thanks again everyone! keep on helping each other ;)

This should do the job as expected, it is only one such option:


=CHOOSEROWS(B4:D8,XMATCH(SEQUENCE(SUM(E4:E8)),SCAN(0,E4:E8,SUM),1))


The above formula uses ETA LAMBDA() if you don't have access to it, then use the following:
=CHOOSEROWS(B4:D8,XMATCH(SEQUENCE(SUM(E4:E8)),SCAN(0,E4:E8,LAMBDA(x,y,x+y)),1))

Note that I have reduced the numbers in the output only to show that it works for the given query.

One another way without, using LAMBDA() helper, bit rusty though.
=LET(
     a, E4:E8,
     b, SEQUENCE(,MAX(a)),
     c, TOCOL(IFS(b<=a,B4:B8&"|"&C4:C8&"|"&D4:D8),2),
     TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER("|"&c,"|",{1,2,3}),"|"))


Or,
=TEXTSPLIT(CONCAT(REPT(B4:B8&"|"&C4:C8&"|"&D4:D8&"_",E4:E8)),"|","_",1)



I like the first solution. It's very clever. Would it work if we replaced CHOOSEROWS with INDEX?

@z.. should be working --> =INDEX(B4:D8,XMATCH(SEQUENCE(SUM(E4:E8)),SCAN(0,E4:E8,SUM),1),{1,2,3})

thank you thank you so much! for the fast respond and easy solution. i tried on the first formula you shared and worked well. :)
